# Insert Current Timestamp in HIVE as part of a Multi Line Insert

Tags: hive, insert, timestamp

I am currently attempting a **Multi Line Insert** into a table in hive.

I want the timestamp to be added via the timestamp function at **Runtime**. I however get an error (See below)

Pls Note: There are many lines in my Multi Line Insert- I have only pasted 2 here as an example.

**Insert Statement**

```
    INSERT INTO kpi01_reference.kp_source_table(event_ref, posting_group, posting_description, posting_account_number, posting_date)
VALUES
    ('P1A', 'AP', 'APM', '31',current_timestamp()),
    ('P1A', 'PA', 'AMP', '3150',current_timestamp())
;
```

**ERROR** 
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10293]: Unable to create temp file for insert values Expression of type TOK_FUNCTION not supported in insert/values

This is my table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE kpi01_reference.kp_source_table(
event_ref string, 
posting_group string, 
posting_description string, 
posting_account_number string, 
posting_date timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the **current_timestamp()** function is a **TOK_FUNCTION** as referred by the error statement such functions are not allowed in insert statements using the **VALUE** keyword.

However there is a way around. You will have to use a dummy table and select required values from it.

Try below and it will work, change your inserts accordingly.

```
INSERT INTO kpi01_reference.kp_source_table(event_ref, posting_group, posting_description, posting_account_number, posting_date)
select 'P1A', 'AP', 'APM', '31',current_timestamp() from (select 1 ) tmp;
```